# scons: foiling an IDE when using alternate build directories

Tags: scons

So I have scons working with an alternate build location (`build/` for my output files, `src/` for my input files) and it works great. Except for one thing.

I'm using an IDE (TI Code Composer 4) to debug my program. I point the IDE at the output executable to run it, and what it uses for the source files for debugging is the `build/` directory. I don't really care, except when I go to edit the file in the IDE, for example `main.cpp`, the file is really `build/main.cpp` which gets clobbered as soon as I run scons again. I have to remember to edit `src/main.cpp` instead. I am aware of this issue and yet I make the same mistake often.

Is there a way to have scons make the source files it copies into the build path read-only? (I'd ask how to get TI CCS4 to use the right source files when it is debugging an executable, but I doubt I'd get any answers.)

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://www.scons.org/wiki/InstallTargets) has information about wrapping InstallTargets with a chmod call.

FYI, the [scons user list](http://scons.tigris.org/ds/viewForumSummary.do?dsForumId=1272&currentPage=1) is quite active with many knowledgeable people and you can get answers pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You could always tell scons not to duplicate source files in the build directory:

```
SConscript('src/SConscript', variant_dir='build', duplicate=0)
```